# Lastest versiob of fullcalendar compatible with jQuery 1.12

Tags: fullcalendar

What is the lastest version of fullcalendar compatible with jQuery 1.12 ?
I can't find this information.

Comment: have you tried the latest version

Comment: I'm not convinced that if software providers don't document their stuff properly, that it becomes SO's responsibility to answer support questions.

Comment: what's the reason? Do you still require support for IE8 or below? That's the only reason to stick with jQuery 1.x. Otherwise you should go to the 2.x branch - there are no breaking differences apart from the removal of support for older IEs. If you want to a bit bolder go for 3.x. There are some differences, but well documented, and probably not an issue for most people, but you can look it up easily enough. There are migration tools as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23139871/5947043 for a quick summary of the 1.x -> 2.x path

Comment: I want to create plugin, where "base" jQuery is in 1.12 version. I'm thinking about use jQ v3 as additional script (use only with calendar) but I'm afraid about website size.

Answer (score 2):

Such information can usually be found the the [changelog](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

> ### [v3.0.0 (2016-09-04)](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v300-2016-09-04)
>
> [...]
>
> jQuery: minimum support raised to v2.0.0

So the latest version of FullCalendar that supports jQuery 1.12 is *probably* 2.9.1.

But be aware that jQuery 1.12 is very old and does not get any updates anymore. You should have a very good reason to stick with such an outdated version.